# How to understand the "ReactContext" in "Sending events to Javascript" in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use the method sendEvent(), but how to get the ReactContext reactContext?

```
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                   String eventName,
                   @Nullable WritableMap params) {reactContext
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  .emit(eventName, params);}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to use a static reference to ReactInstanceManager; you can obtain it by calling `getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager()`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this tentatively by saving a static reference to the `ReactInstanceManager` on the `MainActivity` class, and adding a `public static getContext()` method. It doesn't feel right, but it seems to work.

```
public final class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    private static ReactInstanceManager sReactInstanceManager = null;

    /* [...] */

    @Override
    protected ReactInstanceManager createReactInstanceManager() {
        ReactInstanceManager manager = super.createReactInstanceManager();
        sReactInstanceManager = manager;
        return manager;
    }

    public static ReactContext getContext() {
        if (sReactInstanceManager == null){
            // This doesn't seem to happen ...
            throw new IllegalStateException("Instance manager not available");
        }
        final ReactContext context = sReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
        if (context == null){
            // This really shouldn't happen ...
            throw new IllegalStateException("React context not available");
        }
        return context;
    }

    /* [...] */
}
```

`createReactInstanceManager()` is called by `ReactActivity`'s `onCreate()` method, so I presume it's safe to assume that `sReactInstanceManager` will point to the correct instance, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: Although this method performs the intended functionality correctly, I've downvoted it because this because saving context as a static variable is discouraged behavior. In this case, it is more than likely innocuous, but can cause memory leaks.